# Twig issue with divisibleby()

Tags: templating, php

First sorry for my bad english.

What i want to do: display comments on a page, one at the right one at the left.

My code look like this:

```
{% for i in 0.. NbComment %}
   {% if  (i is divisibleby(2)) or (i == 0) %}

       <!--Right comment-->

   {% else %}

       <!--Left comment-->

   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It works perfectly except when I only have one comment: it display nothing.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `divisableby` I think using Twig's built-in [odd/even test](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/odd.html) might be easier in this case:

```
{% for i in 0.. NbComment %}

   {% if i is odd %}

       <!--Right comment-->

   {% else %}

       <!--Left comment-->

   {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

And, just to suggest some minor improvements to your Twig, assuming the only difference between your comments is their alignment (left/right), you could do something like this, which would probably be a bit more DRY:

```
{% for i in 0.. NbComment %}

   <div class="comment is-{% i is odd ? 'odd' : 'even' %}">
      <!-- Comment content -->
   </div>

{% else %}

   <p class="error">No comments to display</p>

{% endfor %}
```

With the above code, your comments will have either the class `.is-odd` or the class `.is-even` – making it easy to e.g. float comments either `left` or `right` in your CSS. There's really no need to have a full if/else conditional.

Also, note the `{% else %}` statement in the above `for` loop. The contained markup will output if there are no comments – which is good practice, and will save you yet another conditional :)

Comment: Thanks it worked :)
NbComment is a variable which count the number of comment i have .

    $nbComment = count($c) - 1;

Comment: Cool – I removed most of the answer to only contain the relevant part about using odd/even. Be advised that your loop will run (and print ```<!--Right comment-->``` even if ```NbComment``` is 0 :)

Comment: Hello @Franck, would you mind marking the above answer as accepted, if you're happy with it? Closing questions as "answered" helps keeping the site tidy and informative:)